# How to change iPhone app language during runtime?

Tags: iphone, internationalization, performance

Is there a way to change the application language during runtime?

So, after the change `NSLocalizedString` immediately returns the string for the new language.

What I'm doing now is changing the language using the code below:

```
- (void)onChangeLanguage: (id)sender 
{
    NSArray *lang = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:((InfoWhatever *)sender).language, nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lang forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Current language: %@", currentLanguage);
}
```

The language will change but *only after restarting* the app.

Comment: FWIW, this is how it works on the desktop (Mac), too. Running applications aren't affected by language changes.

Comment: I just answered a similar question, and posted some code [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app

Comment: In my application have a settings page with arabic and english. once i change the language it should flip the view controller and the nslocalizedstrings. It works only once i restart the app. but it should change without closing the app, is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt you can do this, even the Settings app cannot do it.

(When you change the language in the Settings app, the screen goes black, and displays "setting language..." and a progress wheel. After a long wait, you are back in Springboard. It almost looks like the phone reboots.)

Comment: Okay then, the reboot sounds acceptable. Is there any apple policy against quitting?

Comment: I agree with your suppositions - but this is not an answer. Do you have any information about performing a runtime language change?

Comment: @Brandon: Why the downvote? You may not like the answer, but it's how things are. Or do you know it better? Then why don't you show us your better answer?

Comment: Again, you did not provide an answer. You made a guess.

This is an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language

Comment: @Brandon: that's an answer to a different question. And the wording of my answer makes it obvious enough that it is based on assumptions and observations, not on some first-hand information (which I would have cited, if I had it). And nobody provided a different (better) answer, so I still think it's the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, that is a different question. Check out the answer, the answerer clearly had some first-hand knowledge of the subject matter - even if the question was not completely resolved. Your answer provides absolutely no useful information. In addition to being simply wrong, the assertion that 'the Settings app cannot do it' is misleading. Why does it matter that the settings app does not (as opposed to cannot) change the presentation language at runtime? The use case that the asker is pursuing does not require redisplaying localized icons or even involve other applications. The answer is inane.

Comment: @Brandon: why don't you share *your* answer with us?

Comment: It took quite a while for me to devise a solution. I actually ended up using the 'NSLocalizedStringFromTable' macro and the 'AppleLanguages' setting to set and check language settings. I'll write up an actual answer if I have the chance. Maybe you should delete this answer? Seeing an inane yet accepted answer doesn't exactly inspire anyone to spend a whole lot of effort.

Comment: @Brandon So did you come up with a solution? I'm looking for a solution to this same problem

Answer (score 11):

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray* languages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[languages insertObject:@"de" atIndex:0]; // ISO639-1
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but there is a simpler implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly

Comment: This implementation is better. ThomasW is replacing the original contents of the array. This method is inserting the language above what is already there.

Comment: How did this work? at least for iOS 8.2 "[userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];" returns immutable array

Comment: This cause a crash: [__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800003c580

Answer (score 7):

The trick to use specific language by selecting it from the app is to force the NSLocalizedString to use specific bundle depending on the selected language ,

here is the post i have written for this http://learning-ios.blogspot.com/2011/04/advance-localization-in-ios-apps.html

and here is the code of one sample app https://github.com/object2dot0/Advance-Localization-in-ios-apps

Answer (score 7):

You Can do it . Here is the way
http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html

1. In Brief Download and add 2 files to the project

   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2917666/LocalizationSystem/LocalizationSystem.h

   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2917666/LocalizationSystem/LocalizationSystem.m

2
     `#import "LocalizationSystem.h"`

3

```
- (IBAction)btnEnglishClicked:(id)sender {
     LocalizationSetLanguage(@"en");
}
```

4 After you set the language as above

```
AMLocalizedString(@"Key", nil)
```

**Thats it**.

Comment: This sounds like the proper approach to the problem, however since you're not using NSLocalizedString (or its variants) directly, you lose the ability to use genstrings to generate your string tables.  You can likely use this open source implementation of genstrings to detect your functions though: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTLocalizableStringScanner

Comment: But, how about image resources. If there are many images on a screen, we will have to set them explicitly. Any better approach of images?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution that allows you to use `NSLocalizedString`. I create a category of `NSBundle` call `NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage`. The interface is like this.

```
// NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSBundle (RunTimeLanguage)
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [[NSBundle mainBundle] runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
- (NSString *)runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName;
@end
```

The implementation is like this.

```
// NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.m
#import "NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation NSBundle (RunTimeLanguage)

- (NSString *)runTimeLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[appDelegate languageCode] ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle *languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString *localizedString=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:key table:nil];
    return localizedString;
}
@end
```

Than just add import `NSBundle+RunTimeLanguage.h` into the files that use `NSLocalizedString`.

As you can see I store my languageCode in a property of `AppDelegate`.  This could be stored anywhere you'd like.

This only thing I don't like about it is a Warning that `NSLocalizedString` marco redefined.  Perhaps someone could help me fix this part.

Comment: You can '#undef NSLocalizedString' just before you #define it.  That should remove the warning.

Comment: Is it possible to use this method to localize storyboards as well?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add these lines:

```
 #define currentLanguageBundle [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"]]   


 1. NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
            [defaults setObject:@[@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];  [defaults
            synchronize];

 2. _label.text = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Key", nil, currentLanguageBundle, @"");
```

Answer (score -1):

try this: 
 object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[MyBundle class]);

https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I tried your solution on my project but I get an exception: "There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path <localisation.lproj path>". I then noticed that the reason was that I had enabled Size Classes in my storyboard. The same thing happens with your project if you enable Size Classes for your storyboard. Any ideas how this issue can be tackled?

Comment: The question was about "switch during runtime". You suggest to rebuild.