# Help Regarding Multi Language Translation in I Phone Application?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a multi language application...I want user to select language at Runtime..not from settings.
How can I create It????
I know how to Localize the application based on language settings from I phone.
But I want it at runtime.
Please help me out.....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the preferred language of an iPhone app in iOS 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235671/how-to-change-the-preferred-language-of-an-iphone-app-in-ios-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to build your custom solution. For example for a simple .plist file you could have multiple .plist with different languages and depending on the language you set through your app. load a different .plist file.
It is quite some work to do for all the files, xibs and strings. I think you should reconsider doing that, why would people choose to change the language of just your app?