# how to create an IOS app with two languages , English and Arabic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, multilingual

I've created an application in IOS using Xcode, the application is in English only and I want it to be in both English and Arabic . How can I use a UIButton on the top of the home page that changes the language to either English or Arabic ? take in considerations that the application has more than 10 ViewControllers.
PS: I don't want to change the Setting of the Mobile , I want to change the app language only.
Thank you..

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235671/how-to-change-the-preferred-language-of-an-iphone-app-in-ios-4