# changing language programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I'm developing an iphone app and want to have the option to programmatically change the language. For example the user can change the language for spell checking and auto-correction by tapping on the world icon on the iphone keyboard, but the problem is that my app has a custom keyboard so I dont have that key.

Is there a way to create a functionality similar to that world icon key so that I could offer language choices available on the device and the user could select one?

Comment: Sounds like you've gotten into the hairy area of having a custom keyboard, by having a custom keyboard you severely limit your apps multi-regional support. I personally would suggest reconsidering the purpose/value add of the custom keyboard before attempting to solve this problem as I foresee many more beyond this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change iOS app's language on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly)

Comment: See also [How to change iPhone app language during runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576904/how-to-change-iphone-app-language-during-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Milad isn't asking how to change the language per se, but how to change the keyboard type. If so, then I don't think this is possible.

Don't forget that a certain keyboard doesn't necessarily lock into a specific language, like how I can type English using Japanese keyboard. And that certain languages have several keyboard types (Chinese has 3 or 4).