# Localizing iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization

I'm using xCode 4.3.2, For my new iPhone project, I've added strings files for Arabic and English, which work well with iPhone language change. But i need to load/change the App language with UIButton click. Is it possible?

Comment: [How to change iPhone app language during runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576904/how-to-change-iphone-app-language-during-runtime) look for this. May this help you.

Comment: IF the link has solved your question then please accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to change iPhone app language during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576904/how-to-change-iphone-app-language-during-runtime) This may help you.