# change language programmatically using UIPicker IOS

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

how to change the language in IOS using UIPicker?

Languages: English, Chinese (Simplified), Bahasa Malaysia

When user selects Chinese (Simplified) it changes the contents of the labels based on languages above.

here's the code

**ChangeLanguage.h**

```
@interface ChangeLanguageViewController :UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPickerView;
@oroperty (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *languageArray;

#import "ChangeLanguageViewController.h"

@interface ChangeLanguageViewController ()

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.dataSource = self;

languageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"English", @"Chinese (Simplified)", @"Bahasa
 Malaysia", nil];
#pragma mark - UIPickerView Delegate
//return the number of columns to display
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}
//returns the number of rows in each component.
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPicker *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [languageArray count];

#pragma mark -UIPickerView Delegate
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return 30.0;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPicker *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [languageArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304988/reload-storyboard-to-change-locale#comment32113031_21304988

Comment: There's simple/supported way to do this with your own, in-app language picker.

Comment: @jasonCoco: how to do this?

Comment: @user3278013 I'm really sorry, I mean't to write 'There is *no* simple/supported way...' :( You can start reading at the link Marc suggested in comments, but it's not going to be trivial.