# Is there a way to change the iphone application language during runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization

My app supports localization for **english** and **hungary** languages.

I want to make default **language** as hungary instead of **english** if user sets default language other than english or hungary from phone settings .

For eg.If user's phone settings language is French,as my app is not support for french localization , so it should be launched in hungary as default not in english.

I have used following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in app delegate :

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
 [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
 NSLog(@"%@",[NSLocale preferredLanguages]);

 NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

 if ([language isEqualToString:@"en"])
 {
    NSArray *langOrder = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:langOrder forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
 }
 else
 {
    NSArray *langOrder = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hu", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:langOrder forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
 }
```

So, after the change in the language from phone setting `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` immediately returns the string for the new language , ie. correct current language and also entered in correct condition in code.

But language will change only at second time relaunch of the app , not in first time launch.

So how can i do this ?

Thanks..

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576904/how-to-change-iphone-app-language-during-runtime?rq=1

Comment: Problem solved, I just put same code in main.m before before UIApplicationMain() is called.Now worked fine.