# objective c accessing Localizable.strings file content

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, multilingual, localizable.strings

> I have added localisation to my first MAC application for spanish
>   language. So I have Localizable.strings(English) &
>   Localizable.strings(Spanish) files in my project.
>
> When I set spanish as the primary language in my MAC, spanish text is
>   getting displayed in the application. This is fine. But I need to give
>   user an ability to switch b/w english and spanish languages. Can
>   anyone please help me with this.
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question perhaps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576904/how-to-change-iphone-app-language-during-runtime